# Pop up form to enter new submission - Restriction with IE 8

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to make this pop up view for inputting data, basically a PHP submission form. However, it seems that I am hit with many restrictions during my internship. I am *only* allowed to create something that works on IE 8. They want everything on one page, and I am stuck with the pop-up submission form.

Can anyone advise me on how to go around doing it? This is my current script.

```
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x;
            var site = prompt("Please enter the details of the submission");
            if (site != null) {
                x = "Your idea: " + site + " has been successfully submitted!";
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and this is my calling function

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Prompt Box</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

Please advise!

Comment: Is it no good if a solution works on IE9, or Firefox? That would seem like an odd restriction.

Comment: actually the thing is. its a corporate thing, they're using IE8 and they aren't changing it. So, my prototype has to be in IE8, or else they cant run it :/

Comment: Is it IE8 only or is it OK if it works in good browsers aswell?

Comment: Right, so it must work _as a minimum_ in IE8. That's better!

Comment: ONLY IE8, unfortunately. If not i'd be able to run most scripts on chrome :p

Comment: There is nothing in your provided code that won't work in IE8. It doesn't do any form submission as you are talking about but no one will write it for you, you have to at least try writing it.

Comment: Are you saying the above code does not work in IE8?

Comment: the thing is... I have no idea how to write a form submission in a pop up. thus, i'm actually asking for some advice. I'm not asking anyone to help me code it. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction or even give me a website to let me read and learn.

Comment: Apologies Jeremy, I still don't have an answer to my question above. I first thought that the solution had to work in IE8 as a minimum (i.e. at least IE8, with any others a bonus), but you might now be saying that it must not work in any browser other than IE8. Would you clarify?

Comment: If you want a pop up, is a modal `<div>` okay? That's not a separate window, but it's a rectangular box in the middle of the browser pane and usually is fine for the purpose of a pop-up box. Real pop-ups in a new GUI window are sometimes blocked, and the only way to deal with that is to whitelist them in your browser. (Don't let this secondary question distract you from answering the first one please!).

Comment: okay. I'll try the suggested first! Thanks halfer. If not i'll just have to tell them I can't do it.